# Hibernate returning two columns instead one when using setFirstResults & setMaxResults method with Oracle

Tags: oracle, hibernate, rownum

I have a query that selects a single column and I am executing the query in batches using setFirstResults & setMaxResults methods of SQLQuery.

Snippet:

```
SQLQuery query = <query object with query projecting a single column>;
int maxResults = 50;
int batchSize = 50;
for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
     query.setFirstResult(batchSize*i);
     query.setMaxResults(maxResults);
     List resultSet = query.list();
     if(resultSet.isEmpty())
         break;
     //process result set
}
```

I set to true the showSQL parameter in hibernate config to see the query string that hibernate produces. For the first batch, i.e. when i=0 below is the query that hibernate generates:

```
select * from (/* query selecting single column here */) where rownum <= ?;
```

which makes sense since its the first batch and we want results from first row and rownum is used to restrict the number of results to maxResults.

Now for the second and subsequent batch reads, the query hibernate generates is:

```
select * from ( select row_.*, rownum rownum_ from (/*query selecting single column here */) row_ where rownum <= ?) where rownum_ > ?;
```

and you can clearly see, the above query is selecting two columns, one being the row number itself.

So when my query only selects one column, hibernate's version of the query is selecting two.

Is this known issue? Can I do something different or am I doing something wrong?

I don't want to cast the result set into two different types before using/processing it.

Comment: I repeated your example in my environment and I saw, that hibernate produces sql with additional column "rownum ". I think you can't get rid from it. This is a feature to provide pagination of table's rows.

Comment: @Lev But isn't it wrong? If it was always returning two columns, it would still make sense.

Comment: Agree with you. Strange behavior